# MYSQL sort by and lock

Tags: mysql

would a MYSQL sort on the whole table

```
select * from mytable order by col;
```

lock the table or would it be some ranged lock depending on the process state?
or would there be no lock?

Comment: `SELECT *` locks the entire table in my experience.

Comment: At minimum, you need to tell us which storage engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In so far as I'm aware, it locks nothing in the default isolation level (i.e. read committed). See:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 0):

Dpends on the engine your tables are using. MyISAM performs table-locking, whilst InnoDB performs row-locking. There are a variety of things to consider, not only downright performance figures.

See [this guide](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine/part_3.html), it is old but still somewhat relevant.

For a more technical whitepaper on db engine comparisons , you can [get one from sun's website](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql_wp_storage_engine_guide.php), though Registration is sadly required.